# python see the code and try to help me friends

Tags: python, python-3.x

prices = {
    '1': 1000,
    '2': 2000,
    '3': 3000,
    '4': 4000,
    '5': 5000,
}

def get_total_challan_cost():
    total_price = 0

```
while True:
    challan_type = input("Enter the Challan Type: ")

    if challan_type == "":
        break

    price = prices[challan_type]
    total_price += price

    print("The price for Challan is: {}".format(price))

print("")
print("Total price: {}".format(total_price))
```

def main():
    # code that generates machine_cost, diesel_cost etc ...

```
# machine_cost = ...?
# diesel_cost = ...?
challan_cost = get_total_challan_cost()

# print(machine_cost + diesel_cost + challan_cost + ...)
```

if **name** == "**main**":
    main()

## till here it is ok

now i print the below in new line
print(get_total_challan_cost)
it should give only total challan cost with not taking again input

Comment: There is only one input? Sum of what other inputs?

Comment: Could you please specify what exactly do you want to sum and what is the expected output?

Comment: I assume OP means for each iteration of the `while` loop

Comment: that program will iterates till we type space

Comment: Enter the the Challan Type : 1
the price for Challan is : 1000
Enter the the Challan Type : 4
the price for Challan is : 4000
Enter the the Challan Type : 5
the price for Challan is : 5000

Comment: @Dhanvanth yes, we can see your code but in order to help you out we need a bit more specific request i.e. what should be the product of summation and what exactly do you expect to have as an output?

Comment: @Dhanvanth I'm not sure, if I fully understand what you want achieve. But if you want to return the sum of all challan types, you need to store the individual values in a list for example. Create a global list, and each time the user enters a number, add the corresponding value to the list. Once the while loop is exited calculate the sum of the list

Comment: i dont know how to do brother can you help me

Comment: @Dhanvanth, Please check Phydeaux's solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an accumulator variable for the total cost so far, and a `dict` for the prices.

Try something like this:

```
prices = {
    '1': 1000,
    '2': 2000,
    '3': 3000,
    '4': 4000,
    '5': 5000,
}

def get_total_challan_cost():
    total_price = 0

    while True:
        challan_type = input("Enter the Challan Type: ")

        if challan_type == "":
            break

        price = prices[challan_type]
        total_price += price

        print("The price for Challan is: {}".format(price))

    print("")
    print("Total price: {}".format(total_price))

def main():
    # code that generates machine_cost, diesel_cost etc ...

    # machine_cost = ...?
    # diesel_cost = ...?
    challan_cost = get_total_challan_cost()

    # print(machine_cost + diesel_cost + challan_cost + ...)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot brother for your help  can you say any websites where i can learn pythod coding good

Comment: @Dhanvanth I can't recommend any Python tutorial specifically, but there are lots on the internet that will help you cover the basics. A good principle of programming *in general* is DRY - "don't repeat yourself". If you find yourself writing a program with a lot of `if`-`else` statements containing almost-identical blocks of code, try to figure out how to refactor it.

Comment: @Dhanvanth you're welcome. If this answer solves your problem, consider accepting it :-)

Comment: in the above everything is good but i want to print total price  in other line it is not working     (total_price)

Comment: @Dhanvanth I.e. what does the output look like now, and what do you want it to look like?

Comment: the output giving the addition of all inputs

Comment: but in another line when entering  total_price   showing error

Comment: total_price                  NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-17467249db60> in <module>()
----> 1 print("Total price: {}".format(total_price))
      2 
      3 if __name__ == "__main__":
      4     main()

NameError: name 'total_price' is not defined

Comment: @Dhanvanth are you running exactly the code I posted above? If not, please edit the code you are running into the question.

Comment: bro i running exactly your code it working perfectly

Comment: but when i enter total_price in new line it showing error

Comment: @Dhanvanth you are entering `total_price` as input to the program? That will not work, just hit `<Enter>`

Comment: no iam enter values like 1  ,  2, 4, 5 it giving total value as the output

Comment: @Dhanvanth so what is the problem?

Comment: but the value which i get from the input i need it to print in one variable so i can add that value with few other categories

Comment: Enter the Challan Type: 1
The price for Challan is: 1000
Enter the Challan Type: 2
The price for Challan is: 2000
Enter the Challan Type: 5
The price for Challan is: 5000
Enter the Challan Type: 
Total price: 8000

Comment: total_price                                               NameError: name 'total_price' is not defined

Comment: if u give your number i will send the images to whatsapp

Comment: @Dhanvanth you say "it working perfectly" but you are getting an error? My code does not cause that error, so what code are you running? Please edit the code that is causing the error **at the end** of the question, do not overwrite the original question.

Comment: i want the output to be saved in one variable so that i can use that variable with few other variables

Comment: @Dhanvanth it is already in the `total_price` variable. If you are trying to use that variable and getting `NameError: name 'total_price' is not defined`, then you are trying to use it somewhere it is not in scope. Are you trying to use it outside the `main` function?

Comment: @Dhanvanth then don't do that

Comment: there are other categories like total labourcost, machinecost, dieselcost so i need to add these program total value to these values

Comment: @Dhanvanth if you need to use that value outside the `main` function, then you need to `return` it. But then the function shouldn't really be called `main` any more...

Comment: if u give me your number i can send what i exactly want through prictures

Comment: brother as per your code challan_cost = get_total_challan_cost()
i need to enter again values

Comment: @Dhanvanth yes, `get_total_challan_cost` is the same code as the original answer

Comment: @Dhanvanth I think at this point you should ask a new question, including all the code that you are trying to make work and explaining clearly what you want to do.

Comment: @Dhanvanth and I am not going to give out my contact details on Stack Overflow